# Delete selected datatable row from database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms, datatable

I have a datatable in a DataGridView in C#. I filled this table with values obtained from a MySql database. Right now it can successfully retrieves the database table and adds to it once I added any new values to the datatable on WinForm side. This is the code for this purpose:

```
dbDataset.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed); // dbDataset is my datatable name
```

and

```
    private static void Row_Changed(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
            // here sda is my MySqlDataAdapter
            try
            {
                MySqlCommandBuilder cmdb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(sda);
                dbDataset.GetChanges();
                dbDataset.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
                dbDataset.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
                dbDataset.GetChanges(DataRowState.Detached);
                dbDataset.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
                dbDataset.GetChanges(DataRowState.Unchanged);                    
                sda.Update(dbDataset);                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
    }
```

But now I found that when I want to delete any row from the table, for instance I select a row and press "delete" key, it shows on the screen that it is deleted, but once I reload my WinForm, it still is there. Obviously it didn't delete that selected row from the database. For that, after some search, I added these parts:

```
dbDataset.RowDeleted += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Deleted);
```

and

```
    private static void Row_Deleted(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        dbDataset.AcceptChanges();
    }
```

By debugging, I found that when I press "delete" key, it enters the `Row_Delete` function, then to `Row_Changed` function, but throws an exception, saying:

```
Additional information: Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.
```

I searched to get the current row index of selection, so that I could use DataRow.delete method like:

```
CurrencyManager xCM = = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[this.dataGridView1.DataSource, this.dataGridView1.DataMember];
```

and in the `Row_Deleted` function I added:

```
DataRowView xDRV = (DataRowView)xCM.Current;
DataRow xDR = ((DataRowView)xCM.Current).Row;
xDR.Delete();
```

but it gives out null exception, saying the datasource of dataGridView1 cannot be null.

Is there any idea for how to delete the selected row from database? Thanks in advance.

Comment: AcceptChanges is tricky. It doesn't update anything on the database. It only accepts the changes on the in-memory DataTable. If you call it nothing will be written to the database because the state of every row is resetted to Unchanged and the deleted rows are removed from the datatable

Comment: So what should I do to delete also from the database then?

Comment: The code in the Row_Changed event should work (remove the GetChanges calls that are not needed) However, I would write that code in a button_click event (a Save button) instead of executing it for every single rowchanged. And If I remember well, the Update call will cause a recursive call to RowChanged.

Comment: Indeed it's tricky :) I did it as you said, deleted all those GetChanges calls in Row_Changed function, then only kept the dbDataset.AcceptChanges() line in Row_Deleted function. Now it works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: I think it works just because you make a change after the deletion. The call to RowChanged with the Update call is the one that updates your database with the changes. If you just delete a row without any other changes I think that your row is not removed from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two distinct methods for the updates. One for the Insert/Update and one for the Delete.
When you delete a Row the framework will call the RowDeleted event handler, not the RowChanged.

```
private static void Row_Changed(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlCommandBuilder cmdb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(sda);
        sda.Update(dbDataset);                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void Row_Deleted(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Update(dt);                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

You should remove the [AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) call. According to MSDN

> When you call AcceptChanges on the DataSet, any DataRow objects still
>   in edit-mode end their edits successfully. The RowState property of
>   each DataRow also changes; Added and Modified rows become Unchanged,
>   and Deleted rows are removed.